# Update dnsmasq with information from avahi

Tags: networking, dns

This seems like something everybody may want, but I'm very surprised to see that there is not solution to my problem (that I can find).
What I want is to run a local DNS server (done) and upstream `.local` request to avahi.
I don't understand why something as simple seems to be quite impossible.
My motivation is to be able to reach any node on my network by name from any other device, for example android devices.

Isn't a service that is capable to act as an DNS aggregator of all the methods available to resolve names? WINS, mDNS, normal DNS, expand hostnames from dhcp...

Comment: I resorted to installing bonjour (extracted from iTunes install)/avahi on every important device I need access to, after I decided I didn't want to set up a dedicated dnsmasq server for dhcp, and didn't want to mess with more robust DNS solutions.  following for alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same problem, and got things going with the following:

(0) Install and configure `avahi-daemon`

(1) Install `libnss-mdns`

(2) In `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, configure your `hosts` line as so:

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

(3) In `dnsmasq.conf`, ensure you don't have the `no-hosts` option, because we want to backend on the system NSS. Then, set up `.local` as your default domain:

```
local=/local/
domain=local
expand-hosts
```

(4) Restart `dnsmasq`, and DNS queries should now fallback against mDNS.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I've configured my system the way you did and it doesn't appear that dnsmasq is resolving through NSS at all. Looking through dnsmasq source I don't see it attempting to resolve through libc (which goes to NSS) either.

Answer (score 0):

I ended using my DNS server, pihole, as a DHCP server too. If you provide a local domain name and fixed-named IPS to your DHCP clients, you will be able to use that name + local domain name to reach them.
So for example, from my mac I use `octopi.local` but from my android phone I can use `octopi.home` where `.home` it's my local domain name, and `octopi` is the name I gave to the fixed DHCP entry that corresponds to my octopi server. Not as automatic as avahi, but at least it works.